# Why does Chrome lag while gaining focus on a textarea containing all of "Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets"?

Tags: html, google-chrome

I'm using Google Chrome Version 46.0.2490.86 (64-bit). (I haven't tested this on any other browsers).

I have a textarea tag and I'm copy + pasting a large number of characters into it (the entire text of "Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets", which is about half a million characters).

Here's an example to try it out on. You can copy the text from [here](http://cdn.preterhuman.net/texts/literature/books_by_title/G%20-%20M/JK%20Rowling%20-%20(2)%20Harry%20Potter%20and%20the%20Chamber%20of%20Secrets%2087000%20words.txt).

```html
<textarea id="input-text" style="width: 100%; height: 250px;"></textarea>
```

Has anyone done this before? Do you know why gaining focus would take so long, when (say) scrolling does not? Are there any workarounds? Is this fundamentally flawed? (I'm developing a page where entire books may get uploaded into a textarea).

Comment: Just to get this straight: you're asking why switching focus to an textarea with a half million characters in it has some lag? Is that right?

Comment: I can reproduce on Chromium 51. Firefox has no such problem.

Comment: @Oriol: Firefox has no such problem -- that's so strange! So I assume Chrome is reading the entire content of the textarea when it gains focus for some reason -- any idea what that might be? More practically, any idea how to work around it? Maybe use another HTML tag or something.

Comment: @EliRose Try reporting this bug to the developers (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/)

Comment: lets say the problem is in chrome.